# I need to wait a certain amount of time before loading the next component in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, settimeout

My api key restricts me from making more than 1 request in 5 second, so I would like to wait 5 seconds before making another request for NearbyJobs(The first request is made for PopularJobs).

```
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} horizontal={false}>   
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: SIZES.medium }}>
      <Welcome />
      <Popularjobs />
      {/* {setTimeout(() => {}, 6000)} */}
      <Nearbyjobs />
    </View>
</ScrollView>
```

API Call

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const useFetch = (endpoint, query) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: `https://jsearch.p.rapidapi.com/${endpoint}`,
    params: { ...query },
    headers: {
      "X-RapidAPI-Key": "",
      "X-RapidAPI-Host": "jsearch.p.rapidapi.com",
    },
  };
  const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await axios.request(options);
      setData(response.data.data);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err);
      alert(err);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const refetch = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetchData();
  };
  return { data, error, loading, refetch };
};
export default useFetch;
```

Comment: Can you share the`api` call?

Comment: @devpolo const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: `https://jsearch.p.rapidapi.com/${endpoint}`,
    params: { ...query },
    headers: {
      "X-RapidAPI-Key": "",
      "X-RapidAPI-Host": "jsearch.p.rapidapi.com",
    },
  };

Comment: Can you share the `useFetch` hook ?

Comment: @devpolo is it possible to make some changes here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using `setTimeout` inside the `useEffect`?

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();

  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, 6000);
  return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
}, []);
```

Comment: This makes a new request every 6 seconds, the previous code would make only 1 request

Comment: Essentially I would only like to make 2 requests that are 6 seconds apart

Comment: I have updated my answer :) This should work

Comment: Thank You.  I believe this is causing a 6 second delay but it is still showing 429 error. I'm not sure what is causing this as both the elements are trying to still load at once

Comment: Are you having a specific error message?

Comment: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 429

Comment: I'm not sure on how to log the error, I've console logged the error and the same thing is being shown

Comment: https://rapidapi.com/letscrape-6bRBa3QguO5/api/jsearch/pricing This is the link for the api subscription plan

Comment: After your `catch (err)` in your `useFetch`, can you add `console.error(error?.response?.data?.error?.message)` and `console.error(error.request)`

Comment: undefined
at jobsift-starter/hook/useFetch.js:23:19 in fetchData
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals

Comment: Is it possible that you've reach the maximum of 500 call/month?

Comment: No there are more calls left